# Фон итема в listView

Tags: android, java

Нужно чтобы первый итем в ListView был серого цвета, а остальные белые. В адаптере пишу следующее:

```
if (i == 0) {
        someView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
}
```

Цвет меняется, но если в списке больше элементов, чем вмещается в список до появления скроллинга - то при скроллинге каждый 5-ый элемент имеет серый цвет, хотя серый должен быть только первый элемент. Я понимаю, что литствью не создает новые элементы при скроллинге а перерисовывает старые, но понять как избавится от этого не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена. решение банально простое - добавил else.